# update column if date is older than 30 days

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where I have column name 'date' and another column with the name 'status' if I use a cron job to run everyday and check if the date is older than 30 day then to change the status to  expired, what code do I need to run using mysqli and php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL event scheduler is more better.

1. Start MySQL event scheduler by executing following query in PhpMyAdmin or MySQL command prompt.

Enter this.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

1. This will update your table.

   CREATE EVENT newEvent
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
   DO
   UPDATE table SET status="expired" WHERE datefield<=CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY;

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET status="expired" where YOURDATEFIELD < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month);
```

Comment: what can I do if my column date contain multiple entries that I keep for records, for example:
user with id 343 last logged in on date 2013-10-2 00:12:54 - 
user with id 343 last logged in on date 2013-10-3 20:12:54
how do I tell the query to check the last date record

Comment: As per my suggestion you should create another table for keeping the record of logged in and update the original record. there there will be execute two query first is to insert the logged in time and userid to one table and after that one update query will be execute for update the record i mean date field of user table.

Answer (score 1):

Use `INTERVAL` in your UPDATE query..

```
UPDATE table SET status="expired" WHERE datefield<=CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```